# codeigniter how to change www.mudomain.org/MyController to www.mydomain.org?

Tags: php, codeigniter, url

I'm using codeigniter, and removed `index.php` with `.htaccess, I have set the default controller, but I can't access my website with`www.mydomain.org`, now it is accessable with`www.mydomain.org/MyController`.
and the router code in`route.php`:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'Main';
$route['(:any)'] = "Main/index";
```

Comment: set the value in `application/config/routes.php` file. `default_controller` variable

Comment: @Sundar I have set that, but not solved

Comment: what error are you getting now. can you show me the router code too

Comment: @Sundar 404 page not found error occur if I remove the MyController part from url, I'm not using from router, I should use that

Comment: add your router code here first

Comment: `$route['default_controller'] = 'Mycontroller';` you should add like this to mention the default controller. Use your file name as `Mycontroller.php` and class name as `Mycontroller` and check it again

Comment: @Sundar file name of my controller is `Main.php` and it is class name is also `Main`

Comment: check your `config.php` base_url value